# Can Vite/Rollup be configured to only run vue-tsc on dependencies that are included by entrypoints?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vite, rollupjs

I have a Vue 2 project that I am in the process of upgrading to Vue 3.  Because the Vue CLI is end of life, I have decided to migrate to Vite.  There were a lot of breaking changes, so pretty much every file in my /src folder needs some degree of refactoring.

I would like to work on one section at a time, and I do not want vue-tsc to try transpiling any code that is not a dependency of any output files.  Presently, it's trying to transpile *EVERY* .ts and .vue file in my /src folder.  Is there a way to configure my project to work the way I am describing?

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    outDir:'../wwwroot/dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: { 
        cards: fileURLToPath(new URL('./src/pages/cards/cards.ts', import.meta.url)),

      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: `[name].js`,
        chunkFileNames: `chunks/[name].js`,
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }      
    },
  },  
})
```

Comment: Based on my experience, Vite does not include any code that is considered dead code (i.e., not imported in any entry files) in the production build by default. If you want to confirm this, you can create a new project and test it out.

Comment: While that may be the case, the transpiler is still working as I describe above.

Comment: I apologize, but I am still unclear on your meaning. Could you please clarify whether you are referring to `transpile` in the context of a development build or a production build?  I'm pretty sure that, Vite will only transpile the files that are actually used within your project by default, rather than transpile everything

Comment: @Duannx updated question wording for clarity.  I also believe I have the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question is a bit of a misnomer because while the error is emitted from running the scripts Vite build process, it's vue-tsc that causes it.

My scripts section of package.json looks like this:

```
"dev": "vite",
"build": "run-p type-check build-only",
"watch": "vite build --watch",
"preview": "vite preview",
"build-only": "vite build --emptyOutDir",
"type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
```

As part of the build process, vue-tsc (Vue's ts compiler for SFCs) runs.  It picks up everything, even files that are not used in the project.  So just using the `build-only`command runs the build and skips the type checking.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for Vite's [build as library](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode).

By default, the build includes the specified entries and the contents of `public` folder.

Any module imported by the included entries can be excluded from build by declaring as `external` ***<sup>1</sup>*** (the `import` is replaced with a `require()` in the output). If not, they'll be included (minified).

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - a notable exception is when your lib has `.jsx` or `.tsx` exports, in which case Vite will include [automatic JSX runtime](https://github.com/alloc/vite-react-jsx#faq). When exporting react components, it can be avoided using `jsxRuntime: 'classic'` in `react` plugin's options. I'm guessing it's the same for `vue()`, but I've never used jsx in Vue.